# prestashop/blocklayered - a way to propagate the current page value to all the page components?

Tags: module, pagination, categories, prestashop

I've just found that if one uses the blocklayered module, the current page param ($p, from FrontController) is not updated globally when you change page. That means that the relative smarty var is available only in some really small areas such as ul.pagination in pagination.tpl. That's probably due to the ajax nature of the module.

And that's awful. I need pagination data outside that small chunks and in every point of all the category tpl components. It should in fact be like this, since there a $p var in the FrontController that doesn't get updated and also you cannot read in $_GET or $_POST, and obviously it should. At least it should be posted, or there should be some kind of hook to read it onchange.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to at least 'expand' the scope of $p.

In pagination.tpl, wrap the ul.pagination in a say, div.pagination-box

Then CAREFULLY modify blocklayered.js, expecially in reloadContent(), in the ajax onsuccess callback so that what's updated is div.pagination-box instead of ul.pagination.

That lets me get the updated {$p} in div.pagination-box (and since is a child, also in ul.paginationof course). So I can add arbitrary things OUTSIDE ul, in div.pagination-box.

Hope it helps people having the same issue.

Anyway, it would be really good to have always the updated $p in every chunk of every .tpl.

If anyone find a better solution, please post here.